# Add random class from an array to every specified element, excluding last used class

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have an array with classes and i want to apply random class from this array to specified elements - this is simple. But i need to avoid situation like two or more elements in a row has the same class.

For now i have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = ["bg1", "bg2", "bg3", "bg4", "bg5"];

    $(".img-cap").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
    });
});
```

Comment: How does the row containing the `.img-cap`s look like?

Comment: What is wrong with simply keeping the last chosen random value in some var and check against that to avoid repetition?

Comment: Do all the entries in your classes array has to be used? Or is it fine as long as it's not repeating itself?

Comment: @jrook There is nothing wrong i think but how to do this?

Comment: @entiendoNull There will be at least 20 elements and only five classes so every need to be used. Eventually they could go one by one but I would prefer randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to save the last random value in a variable then remove it from the array. On the following iteration, the class will not be in the array, so it will be impossible to use the same class twice. What's important though is to push the last used class **after** selecting a new random class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = ["bg1", "bg2", "bg3", "bg4", "bg5"], last_class;

    $(".img-cap").each(function(){
     var rdm_int = ~~(Math.random()*classes.length);
        var rdm_class = classes.splice( rdm_int, 1 )[0];
        if( last_class ) classes.push( last_class )
        $(this).addClass( rdm_class );
        last_class = rdm_class;
    });
});
```

```css
.img-cap{
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px
}

.bg1{background:red}
.bg2{background:blue}
.bg3{background:yellow}
.bg4{background:orange}
.bg5{background:purple}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
<div class="img-cap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit different than what you want, but this will run until there are no more classes in the list, each time randomly picking one and assigning it. Vanilla JS solution as well.

```
//Running as many times as there are items in classes
for (i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
    var randomPick = Math.floor(Math.random()*classes.length)+1];

    //Change this to target whatever you are adding the classes to
    document.getElementsByClassName("img-cap").classList.add(classes[randomPick]);

    //Will edit the class list, removing it so it may not be picked again
    classes.splice(randomPick,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the random number first, and then use the `hasClass()` method to determine whether or not to apply it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = ["bg1", "bg2", "bg3", "bg4", "bg5"];

    $(".img-cap").each(function(){
        var class_to_add = ~~(Math.random()*classes.length);
        console.log(class_to_add);
        if($(this).hasClass(classes[class_to_add]) === false) {
            $(this).addClass(classes[class_to_add]);
        }
    });
});
```

Full disclosure here, I had no idea what `~~(Math.random()*classes.length` would produce prior to this post, so thank you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which asked how to prevent the same class from being added to two elements in a row, not how to prevent the same class from being added to an element twice.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the classes array and then use the clone to set the class and remove all classes from the clone until there is nothing left. Then clone again.

```js
var classes = ["bg1", "bg2", "bg3", "bg4", "bg5"];
var classesClone = classes.slice(0); // clone classes

$('.img-cap').each(function(){
    if(0 == classesClone.length) {
        // lets clone again if classesClone is empty
        classesClone = classes.slice(0);
    }

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * classesClone.length);
    
    $(this).addClass(classesClone[randomNumber]);
    classesClone.splice(randomNumber, 1); // remove item from clone which has just been used
});
```

```css
.row {
   border:solid 1px black;
   float: left;
}
.img-cap {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bg1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.bg2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.bg3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg4 {
  background-color: navy;
}

.bg5 {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
  <div class="img-cap"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.
It would random the classes being used, and once used it would remove that entry from the your `classes array`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = ["bg1", "bg2", "bg3", "bg4", "bg5"];

    $(".img-cap").each(function(){
        var cssClass = classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)],
            index = classes.indexOf(cssClass)

        classes.splice(index, 1);

        $(this).addClass(cssClass);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var classes = ["bg1", "bg2", "bg3", "bg4", "bg5"];
    var temp ='a';
    var x = 'a';
    $(".img-cap").each(function(){
        while(x===temp)
            x = classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]
        temp = x
    //console.log(x)
    $(this).addClass(x);
    });
});
```

At every iteration in the `foreach` loop, the while loop constantly chooses a random class until the selected class becomes different than the class selected in the previous iteration thus guaranteeing no two consecutive elements get the same class.

Karl-André Gagnon's asnwer is more thorough to be sure (faster, too). But if you have just a few classes to choose from, the while loop above should not take long before it produces a new value. If there are many classes, then Karl's solution may be the better option.